# Is @Scheduled thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a MongoRepository interface:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument,String> {}
```

and a `@Component` annotated class which serves as a thread using `@Scheduled` :

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@EnableAsync
public class MyThread {
     @Autowired
     private MyRepository myRepository;

     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
     @Async
     public void saveCurrentTime()
     {
        myRepository.save(someTimeHere);
     }

}
```

My question is:

Is this `@Scheduled` method thread-safe ? The main idea here is to create different `MyThread` beans (`@Scope("prototype")`) which will save the current time in a NoSQL. But what happens if 2 of these "threads" call at the same time `myRepository.save()` method ? Should I handle by myself the synchronization or is it already handled with this annotation ?

Comment: No, it doesn't ask my question. My question is about 2 threads using the same object at the same time, and I just want to know if `@Scheduled` is thread-safe or not.

Comment: No, Spring doesn't do any external coordination. You'll have 1+ instance of `MyThread` and some executor that you've configured will invoke one of those instance's `saveCurrentTime()` method when it's scheduled. That's all.

Comment: Thank you very much.